# Triangle Button Slider In ReactJS/MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui, slider

I'm struggling to make a perfect triangle button instead of a pizza slice button on a slider in Material UI and ReactJS, this is the task I want to complet exemple bellow:

[image]

And this is where I'm currently at:

[image]

//App

```
const CustumSlider = withStyles({
    root: {
        color: "transparent",
        height: 2,
        padding: '15px 0',
    },
    thumb: {
        boxShadow: iOSBoxShadow,
        marginLeft: -16,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        borderLeft: "16px solid transparent",
        borderRight: "16px solid transparent",
        borderBottom: "16px solid #f39200",
        cursor: "pointer",
        marginTop: "9px",
        '&:focus, &:hover, &$active': {
            color: "transparent",
            boxShadow: iOSBoxShadow,
            '@media (hover: none)': {
                boxShadow: iOSBoxShadow,
            },
        },
    },
    valueLabel: {
        left: '-16px',
        top: -25,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontFamily: "Nunito",
        fontWeight: 700,
        '& *': {
            background: 'transparent',
            color: '#f39200',
        },
    },
    track: {
        height: 15,
        borderTopLeftRadius: "5px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "5px",
        color: "#003865",
    },
    rail: {
        height: 15,
        opacity: 0.5,
        borderTopLeftRadius: "5px",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: "5px",
        borderTopRightRadius: "5px",
        borderBottomRightRadius: "5px",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)",
    },
    mark: {
        backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
        height: 8,
        width: 1,
        marginTop: -3,
    },
    markActive: {
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
    },
})(Slider);
```

Is there any solution to getting a triangle button in the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
borderRadius: "0px",
```

to the `thumb` style
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gmmiv?file=/demo.js)